# CSS Sprite Button Using Table... Can't get rid of line breaks after table in IE (quirks mode)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-tables, quirks-mode

I am creating a css button using the following image...

[image: css bg]

This is the background of a table.. the text for the image goes inside td blocks.

You can see it in action here, please view source to see how it all works, css is in-lined.

[css button link](http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/button_sample.html)

Everything appears to be working great... but view it in IE and Firefox.  You'll notice that for some reason there are line breaks in IE and not in Firefox.  I want it to not have the line breaks, firefox style.

I know a lot of people will immediately say "Just add a DOCTYPE tag and all will be well!"
Unfortunately my use case is such that it has to work in I.E. quirks mode.

So..with that being a restriction.. any ideas?

Comment: I just told someone today, that's why you always code to standards and never to browsers....ESPECIALLY Internet Explorer. And reason #9364 you should never use tables for layout.

Comment: I fully agree.. I really really really wish I didn't have to use quirks mode. :/

Comment: Just add `*margin-right: 4px !important;` to the `.spriteTableButton` class to give you spacing on the right. The `*` in the rule will ensure it only applies to IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add "`float:left;`" to css class "`.spriteTableButton`" ? This can solve the problem of linebreak in no time.

Comment: Thanks...That fixes the line break.  However, doing that the buttons have absolutely no space in between each other and the margin does nothing.  I suppose I could add a small div w/ some amount of width but I'd prefer a better solution than that.  Ideas?

Comment: Awesome, if anyone is reading this in the future, be sure to read Strelok's comment above, it fixes the issue with the margin not working.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: OK.  Bad news.  This fix does not work in Safari.  It works for both IE quirks mode and firefox but fails in safari.  I have updated the url .. http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/button_sample.html to show it with your suggested code.  Please have a look in Safari.  Not only are the table breaks still there but the whole thing is now aligned to the right for some reason...

Comment: Ok, the messed up align was due to me removing the * that you suggested so that is back in now... everything aligned middle, which is probably OK.  Still need to get rid of those damn table breaks tho..