# CSS Sprite Button Using Table... Can't get rid of line breaks after table in Safari

Tags: css, button, safari, css-tables

I asked *Almost* this exact same question yesterday.  Basically I have a css button that is built using a table.

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655346/css-sprite-button-using-table-cant-get-rid-of-line-breaks-after-table-in-ie)

The working example is [here](http://www.lolstrategies.com/test/button_sample.html)

It looks great, except that in Safari the buttons stack instead of being next to each other like they should.

Anyone have any ideas on this?  I feel like I've tried everything..

Comment: Can you clarify how this question is different? Otherwise, this question might be closed as duplicate.

Comment: The previous question was IE quirks mode specific.  The answerer answered it correctly for that case.  In this case it is Safari specific and I didn't think it fair not accept his answer since he had gotten the correct answer for the case I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.spriteMediumButton` class, update `margin: 0 auto;` to `margin: 0;`.

Comment: This is perfect, never using auto again!